# Disable Rocket Chat message formatting

Tags: meteor, formatting, themes, chat, rocket.chat

I wanna disable the Rocket Chat formatting like whenever i send a message that contains @@ it will automaticly converts to @ and i wanna disable it globally.
I know there are some solutions like using `` but i want a solution that fix it globally like using custome CSS or custome Script features.

I tried looking in the documentation for finding a solution or a css class or script but there is none.